# Jenkins automatically removes all old builds even though # is set to 10

Tags: jenkins

I have set my Jenkins jobs to discard old builds. I have left "Days to keep builds" empty, and set "Max # of builds to keep" to 10. I checked my jobs today morning and all old builds were empty! :) Is there some hidden setting somewhere I have not noticed that overrides the job configuration?

Comment: I have seen this happen (with the left builds actually being there); have a look in the jenkins home to see if all the builds were really deleted or not (and eventually restart jenkins).

Comment: Had this happening to me once and the fix was to recreate the job

Comment: Restarting the Jenkins service helped me in a similar case.